# Is this etale motivic or motivic cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

I am trying to reconcile my understanding of motivic cohomology (based on the Lecture Notes by Mazza-Voevodsky-Weibel) with the homotopic point of view. I am currently struggling to answer this question that I have.

Let $Sm_k$ be the category of smooth $k$-schemes of finite type, let $\epsilon:\Delta^{op}Shv(Sm_k)_{et}\to \Delta^{op}Shv(Sm_k)_{Nis}$ be the canonical morphism of sites (it might go in the other direction... $\epsilon_*$ goes from et to Nis, and $\epsilon^*$ from Nis to et). If $X$ is a smooth $k$-variety, then I know that $\epsilon^*X=X$, where on the left $X$ is viewed as a sheaf in the Nisnevich topology, and on the right on the etale topology. Define motivic cohomology of a Nisnevich spectrum $S$ as $[S,H\mathbb{Z}]$, where $H\mathbb{Z}$ is the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum.

One definition of motivic cohomology of $X$ is $[\Sigma^{\infty}_T(X)_+,H\mathbb{Z}]$. My question is: what is $[\Sigma^{\infty}_T(R\epsilon_*\epsilon^*X)_+,H\mathbb{Z}]$? Is it etale motivic cohomology or motivic cohomology again?

Also, what is $[\Sigma^{\infty}_T(\epsilon_*\epsilon^*X)_+,H\mathbb{Z}]$? I am not sure if this is something meaningful.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with big sites but I guess you can deduce from faithfully flat decent that $R\epsilon_\star X=X$

Comment: This is called Lichtenbaum cohomology. The homotopy invariant part is what is called étale motivic cohomology in the book of Mazza, Voevosky, Weibel. If $k$ is of characteristic zero, they coincide, but in characteristic $p>0$, étale motivic cohomology is isomorphic to Lichtenbaum motivic cohomology in which we invert $p$. This is quite meaningful. With rational coefficients, this coincides with motivic cohomology, and comparing the difference with motivic cohomology in the case of finite coefficients is the contents of the Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture, proved by Voevodsky and Rost.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski I apologize, but I am not sure if you are talking about $R\epsilon_*\epsilon^*$ or $\epsilon_*\epsilon^*X$. If it's  $\epsilon_*\epsilon^*X$, then your answer contradicts ali's, right?'

Comment: I meant if it's $R\epsilon_*\epsilon^*X$, then you answer contradicts ali's. On the other hand, I now see that since there is a natural map from motivic to Lichtenbaum, the only possibility is that $R\epsilon_*\epsilon^*X$ corresponds to motivic cohomology, and $\epsilon_*\epsilon^*X$ to Lichtenbaum.

Comment: I meant derivedfunctors, applied to the motivic Eisenber-MacLane spectrum. I do not think there is a reasonable answer if you apply these functor on $X$. This looks very unnatural to me.